# Why are canonical transformations made in the first place?

Tags: classical-mechanics, coordinate-systems, hamiltonian-formalism, phase-space

Is it to get cyclic coordinates in the Hamilton's equation?

Comment: That's one application. More generally to simplify.

Answer (score 0):

The canonical transformations are a way to preserve the Hamiltonian description of the dynamic. When you make a canonical transformation the variables are still following a Hamiltonian. 
So all in all it is just a restriction on the variables changes you can make when in hamiltonian description. **Then it just comes down to why you usually make variable change : To simplify the resolution of the problem**. Whether you resolve it by solving the Hamilton equations or by finding the Action and Angle variables and hence say that the phase space is structured in KAM(Kolmogorov–Arnold–Moser) tori.